# setActionBar() min appcompat to use if min minSdkVersion 16

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I have  minSdkVersion 16 and I want to search for the correct support library in order to use method `setActionBar()` (introduced with api level 21).

Which appcompat version should I use? Of course I would not like to use old appcompat as minSdkVersion is 16.

Thanks in advance to all,
Enrico

Answer (score 1):

All appcompat-v7 versions have the **same minSdk=7**.

you should use the **latest version of appcompat**, because it has all current features and all bug fixes.
Currently it is the v23:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
```

Pay attention.
**It requires compileSdkVersion 23.**

If for some reasons you can't use it, you can use one of the appcompat v21 o v22.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

About this point:

> in order to use method `setActionBar()`

It is not clear what are asking, but the with the appcompat library, you should use the `AppCompatActivtity` and the method `setSupportActionBar`.
Check the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gabriele! Where do I find all the possible versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7? For example, why for v21 the version is 21.0.3 and for versions v22 is 22.2.1 (0.3 in the first case and 2.1 in the second)?

Comment: You can find here the full list.
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: Thanks Gabriele. Is there any special reason why the version should match the compileSdkVersion? In my case, I have a minSdk is a previous version. Is it suggested to put compileSdkVersion always at the very last version? Thanks in advance

Comment: In general you should use the same version to compile. They are related to API.